# Dynamic score board using PHP, AJAX, JQUERY & JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Basically I have created an online leaderboared [here](http://test.bmx-tube.com/scores.php) that returns the top 100 user scores

and if users hit refresh and the ranks have changed it will show new positions. What I would like to do is have the ranks updated without doing a page refresh, using AJAX, jQuery and JSON.

The leaderboard is populated via an associative sql query and stored in an sql variable, I have managed to get the output in JSON format seen [here](http://test.bmx-tube.com/ajax.php) using

```
    //Shows user details and the current top 100 ranks
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    print json_encode ($row);
  }
```

So far so good, using this animated sorting example from [Tinysort][3]

```
function sort() {
    var $Ul = $('ul#leaderboard');
    $Ul.css({position:'relative',height:$Ul.height(),display:'block'});
    var iLnH;
    var $Li = $('ul#leaderboard>li');
    $Li.each(function(i,el){
        var iY = $(el).position().top;
        $.data(el,'h',iY);
        if (i===1) iLnH = iY;
    });
    $Li.tsort('h1:eq(0)',{order:'desc'}).each(function(i,el){
        var $El = $(el);
        var iFr = $.data(el,'h');
        var iTo = i*iLnH;
        $El.css({position:'absolute',top:iFr}).animate({top:iTo},500);
    });
}
```

I believe I am most of the way there but I am getting stuck on the poll() function below

```
poll();

function poll() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.bmx-tube.com/ajax.php', // needs to return a JSON array of items having the following properties: id, score, facebook_id, username
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(o) {
            for(i=0;i<o.length;i++) {
                if ($('#row-'+o[i].player_id).length == 0) {
                    // this id doesn't exist, so add it to our list.
                    $("#leaderboard").append('<li><h1 style="display:inline" player_id="row-' + o[i].player_id + '">' + o[i].score + '</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + o[i].facebook_id + '/picture"/> ' + o[i].name + '</li>');
                } else {
                    // this id does exist, so update 'score' count in the h1 tag in the list item.
                    $('#row-'+o[i].player_id).html(o[i].score);
                }
            }
            sort();
        },
    }); 

    // play it again, sam
    var t = setTimeout(poll,3000);
}
```

I have tried changing all the variables around but have had no luck so far.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well firstly your JSON string is invalid. Your server isn't actually returning an array of objects.

Are you using `echo json_encode($yourArray);` to create the JSON server side?

Here is an example of a proper array of objects as a JSON string:

> ```
> {"array":[
>      {"object":"1","description":"this is an object"},
>      {"object":"2","description":"this is an object"},
>      {"object":"3","description":"this is an object"}
> ]}
> ```

**NB:** You can validate JSON strings with JSONLint: http://jsonlint.com/

Also you can use firebug or chrome's inspector tools to see if the object is valid or not, and to view the JSON string being returned by your server in a more intuitive way.

As for accessing the objects once you have a valid object, you can use jQuery `.each()` to do this easily and elegantly.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.bmx-tube.com/ajax.php',
        type: "get", cache:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(ranks) 
        {
            $(ranks).each(function(index, rank)
            {
                if($('#row-'+rank.player_id).length == 0) 
                {
                    // this id doesn't exist, so add it to our list.
                    $("#leaderboard").append('<li><h1 style="display:inline" id="row-' + rank.player_id + '">'+rank.score+'</h1> <img style="height:50px" src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+rank.facebook_id + '/picture"/> ' + rank.name + '</li>');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // this id does exist, so update 'score' count in the h1 tag in the list item.
                    $('#row-'+rank.player_id).html(rank.score);
                }
            });
            //now sort
            sort();
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Ajax error: could not access URL");
        }
    });
```

## Some other things to note

Its a good idea to disable caching on data that changes regularly when using GET with AJAX.
That is what the `type: "get", cache:false,` is doing above.

---

Let me know if you need any further help...this should point you in the right direction though.

Cheers,
Oisin

## --- Edit 1 ---

I realise now what you intended to do with `player_id="row-'+rank.player_id+'"`.
That should actually be `id="row-'+rank.player_id+'"`

I've modified the code above to reflect this.

## jsFIddle

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating how you might go about with what you're trying to do.
I've simplified things by cutting out your sort function for now and just used a very simple sort instead.
I've also broken up the generated HTML into section so you can style them individually and modify the data in a more structured way.
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/fKcKF/6/

**NB:** due to the way jsFiddle works I have had to generate a mock dataset and modify the AJAX function to load it. On your website you would of course be loading the JSON from your own server.

---

if this helps you please **upvote**. If it solves your problem please mark this answer as **correct**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I have reformatted my JSON output and it validates with JSONLint, if you click the link above you can see the now formatted JSON. In case anyone else is looking for something similar I did it like this:

```
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$json = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json['rank'] = ($row['rank_number']);
    $json['player id'] = ($row['player_id']);
    $json['facebook id'] = ($row['facebook_id']);
    $json['name'] = ($row['name']);
    $json['score'] = ($row['score']);
    $data[] = $json;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

I will try the next step when I return home. One thing is still puzzling me though - you mention that I should use 'data-player_id instead of player_id', do you mean in the Ajax script?

Thanks again Oisin for you help it is very much appreciated

Comment: for that `data-player_id` I was referring to how you were storing the player_id as a custom attribute on the DOM element in your callback function. 
It really all depends on what you intend on doing with this data though and if you're worried about how valid your markup is.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you intended now. I'll modify my answer below accordingly. This should also help you with your problem of the ranks just being adding to the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a go using what you suggested, with a couple of amendments, and it now seems to be doing 98% of what I want using the code below:

```
<body>

<h1>This is just to test if it is connecting!</h1>
<ul id="leaderboard"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

poll();

function poll() {

    $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: "get", cache:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(ranks) 
    {
        $(ranks).each(function(index, rank)
        {
            if($('#row-'+rank.player_id).length == 0) 
            {
                // this id doesn't exist, so add it to our list.
                $("#leaderboard").append('<li><h1 style="display:inline"    data-player_id="row-' + rank.player_id + '">' + rank.rank +''+ rank.score +'</h1> <img  class="image" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + rank.name + '/picture"/> ' + rank.name + '</li>');
            } 
            else 
            {
                // this id does exist, so update 'score' count in the h1 tag in the  list item.
                $('#row-'+rank.player_id).html(rank.score);
            }
        });
        //now sort
        sort();
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert("Ajax error: could not access URL");
    }
}); 

    // play it again, sam
    var t = setTimeout(poll,3000);
}

function sort() {
    var $Ul = $('ul#leaderboard');
    $Ul.css({position:'relative',height:$Ul.height(),display:'block'});
    var iLnH;
    var $Li = $('ul#leaderboard>li');
    $Li.each(function(i,el){
        var iY = $(el).position().top;
        $.data(el,'h',iY);
        if (i===1) iLnH = iY;
    });
    $Li.tsort('h1:eq(0)',{order:'desc'}).each(function(i,el){
        var $El = $(el);
        var iFr = $.data(el,'h');
        var iTo = i*iLnH;
        $El.css({position:'absolute',top:iFr}).animate({top:iTo},500);
    });
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

This is just a test call using an html file, you can see the output [here](http://test.bmx-tube.com/leaderboard.html). The only problem now is (apart from it being ugly) is that rather than polling and re-arranging (if necessary) the ranking of users it is just adding to the output like this

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

and so on. Any ideas?

Thanks again

Comment: Hi,
Looks like you're new here. welcome!
It's better if you either add comments to my answer or amend your question to provide updates instead of posting answers to your own question. It can get a bit confusing otherwise, and people trying to help you wont be notified of your updates.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm new here so sorry if I have done anything wrong. I have tried your new solution ' id="row-' but this just takes the last entry score and adds it to the leaders row in the output. I have tried every way I can think of for rearranging the output and even altered the Tinysort function, but still no luck. I'm sure it should be fairly easy but it has me beaten at the moment. All that should be happening is that if the highest scores change then the output should be rearranged to reflect that and if the scores don@t change then nothing should happen. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code in general seems ok to me.
...I'm not entirely sure about your sorting part though. I've not had a chance to review the code entirely. Best to keep things simple at first.
See my edited answer. Here is a jsFIddle that will hopefully help you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/fKcKF/6/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have had a look at the jsFIddle and that seems to be more or less what I was trying to do, I was also looking at doing some kind of auto increment for testing but your solution is far more elegant than anything I could have done. This gives enough to be getting on with and if I figure it out or need any further help I will post. Thank you very much for taking the time to assist me, I greatly appreciate your efforts.

Comment: glad I could help! and yea, if you need any more help just ask.